# Add a progress bar

Tags: jquery

I have following function to show an image file after it's uploaded.

```
<p id="append_image"><div class="append_image"></div></p>

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: upload_image.ajax_url, 
    data: formdata,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    beforeSend : function(){
        jQuery('#append_image').html('Uploading...');
    },
    success : function(data){
        jQuery('#append_image').html('');
        //Here shows the image that is uploaded.
        }
        jQuery('.append_image').append(append_html);
    }
 });
```

Now, it currently shows `"Uploading..."` but I want to show a progress bar and I am not sure how.

I want to use Google material lite version:

```
<div id="p1" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress"></div>
 <script>
  document.querySelector('#p1').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded',   function() {
    this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(44);
  });
</script>
```

Does anyone know how I can add the progress bar here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<div class="progressContainer">
    <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.progressContainer{
    height:10px;
    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.progress{
    width:10%;
    background:green;    
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all .5s ease-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out 0s;
}
```

After this you can move the progress bar by changing width of `.progress` in you jQuery code.

See this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL1Ln940/)**.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. I am not sure how to change the width. In the sample that I added, it simply said "44" as in "44%".  I am not sure how to detect the uploading progress to reflect on the progress change.

Comment: I think that 44 is the data size that has been uploaded and you need to divide it by file size to get percentage of file uploaded and then update that percentage in the width of .progress

Comment: hmm i see. I guess I should do some research on it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. =)